# Unable to handle the promise of $state.reload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have ran into a scenario where when user refreshes the browser, the variable should be set to  false.

My Code :

```
let showVar = true;
if(this.$state.reload(this.$state.current.name)){
            showVar = false;
        }
```

Right now its working. But i can see that $state.reload returns a promise and not sure how to handle that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What routing library are you using? Would it be as simple as `this.$state.reload(this.$state.current.name).then(function() { ... });` ?

Comment: we are using ui-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is

```
let showVar = true;
this.$state.reload(this.$state.current.name).then(() => {
    showVar = false;
});
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But ,i also use showVar with ng-class to apply a div of height : 60px , so even when the flag is set to false the div just shows for milliseconds and vanishes.